# How to configure different timeout for different URLs in Spring Oauth2?

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, settimeout

Lets say I configured two API resources with different URLs:

1. /api/secure/**
2. /api/admin/**

```java
@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(customAuthenticationEntryPoint)
            .and()
            .logout()
            .logoutUrl("/oauth/logout")
            .logoutSuccessHandler(customLogoutSuccessHandler)
            .and()
            .csrf()
            .requireCsrfProtectionMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/oauth/authorize"))
            .disable()
            .headers()
            .frameOptions()
            .disable()
            .and()
            .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api/secure/**").hasAnyAuthority(Authorities.ROLE_USER.name(), Authorities.ROLE_ADMIN.name())
            .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasAnyAuthority(Authorities.ROLE_ADMIN.name());
}
```

and I configured timeout:

1. for refresh token: 1 day;
2. for access token: 30 mins;

```java
@Override
public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
    clients.inMemory()
            .withClient("client01")
            .secret("pass")
            .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(24 * 60 * 60)
            .accessTokenValiditySeconds(30 * 60)
            .scopes("read", "write")
            .authorities(Authorities.ROLE_USER.name(), Authorities.ROLE_ADMIN.name(), Authorities.ROLE_SUPERADMIN.name())
            .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "refresh_token");
}
```

How can I make different timeouts for /api/secure/** (as above) and /api/admin/** (refreshToken: 20 min, accessToken: 10 secs)?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the configuration for a second client with

```
.and()
       .withClient("anotherClient")
       .....
```

The client used at runtime depends on what the client specifies as in :

```
http://localhost:8080/oauth/authorize?
 response_type=code
 &client_id=anotherClient
 &redirect_url=http://client_host?key=value
 &scope=read
```

you can find a good tutorial at [implementing oauth2 with spring security](https://raymondhlee.wordpress.com/2014/12/21/implementing-oauth2-with-spring-security/)